# Python: how to login on Youtube

Tags: python, authentication, youtube, youtube-api

So, I'm a bit confused on how I get past authentication on Youtube using Python and successfully login. I always get error 403 when I try to PragmaticLogin():

```
yt_service = gdata.youtube.service.YouTubeService()
service.developer_key = 'MY Key'
service.client_id='My ID'
service.email = 'myemail@yahoo.gr'
service.password = 'mypassword'
service.source = 'my_program'
service.ProgrammaticLogin()
```

What do I have to do?

**Update:**

I think that it has to do with authentication. Do I need both developer_key and client_id? Where do I get each? I want to have rights to add comments to my videos etc.

Full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bodhi32/Documents/bot.py", line 9, in <module>
    client.ClientLogin(USERNAME, PASSWORD)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/gdata/service.py", line 833, in ClientLogin
    self.ProgrammaticLogin(captcha_token, captcha_response)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/gdata/service.py", line 796, in ProgrammaticLogin
    raise Error, 'Server responded with a 403 code'
gdata.service.Error: Server responded with a 403 code
```

Comment: Maybe the password or the id is wrong? Recheck all the variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ClientLogin is deprecated and has all sorts of errors. Don't use it.
Use OAuth2.

This sample should get you started:

https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/python/my_uploads.py

Comment: That seems useful. Is there a tutorial about all these? I find difficulty understanding the code...

Comment: Here's a video for Java, but it should still be helpful: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ADLmRWZqFOI

Answer (score 0):

Use your code but make sure you fill the `developer_key` and `client_id fields` ( check below how to get them).

```
yt_service = gdata.youtube.service.YouTubeService()
service.developer_key = 'MY Key'
service.client_id='My ID'
service.email = 'myemail@yahoo.gr'
service.password = 'mypassword'
service.source = 'my_program'
service.ProgrammaticLogin()
```

To obtain a youtube api go to 
https://cloud.google.com/console/project and create a new project, then enable youtube.
Check this video for more info [Obtaining a simple API key for use with the YouTube API](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JbWnRhHfTDA)

Comment: No, I think the problem has to do with authentication... Check updated question.